# How to create a desktop shortcut for the SQLite Manager firefox plugin?

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, firefox-extensions

I frequently use the [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) plugin of Firefox for playing around with a light weight database file I've. The problem with this is, whenever I have to open the SQLite Manager, I need to first open Firefox and then open the plugin from it which is quite annoying at times, as I never intend to use Firefox at all.

So is there a way I can create a shortcut for the SQLite Manager firefox plugin on my desktop to directly start it without having to open Firefox first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/issues/detail?id=684) suggestion.  I tried it and it works.

Simply make a new desktop shortcut to Firefox, with this as the target.

```
firefox -chrome chrome://sqlitemanager/content/sqlitemanager.xul
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks :) But I don't get one thing. Why do we use `chrome` for it?

Comment: I wondered that too.  Apparently it's a Mozilla thing, no relation to Google Chrome.  See [Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome).

Comment: God bless you...